# XAML - Showing text or spinner image when processing on button click

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a xaml form (related code is given below). I would like to show text/label or processing image when user clicks search button and it should hide when results are back.

PS: I am not a xaml programmer. I know asp.net mvc (c#) but got this quick task.

Here is the code for the button and label to be displayed:

```
<Button Grid.Row="4" Content="{Binding SEARCH}"  Grid.Column="8" Foreground="White" Command="{Binding ResubmitQuote}" Height="25" x:Name="SearchButton" Click="SearchButton_Click"  >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#753297"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#9966cc"/>
                </Trigger>                                                    
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Label code (this can be replaced by text or image):

```
<Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="8" Foreground="#6B666E" FontSize="10" Padding="20, 8, 0, 0" Content="{Binding SEARCH}" x:Name="searchingLabel" Opacity="0" />
```

I have already tried this

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    this.searchingLabel.Opacity = 1;
}
```

but this shows the label when results are back.

Comment: are you using MVVM Pattern

Answer (score 1):

Create a property in ViewModel

```
private Visibility fieldtest;

public Visibility MyPropertytest
{
    get
    {
        return this.fieldtest;
    }

    set
    {
        this.fieldtest = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("MyPropertytest");
    }
}

     private void ResubmitQuote(object obj)
            {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(MyPropertytest = Visibility.Visible, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal); 

        ////Load your data Here for DataBase

Dispatcher.Invoke(MyPropertytest = Visibility.Collapsed, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    }
```

bind this property with your label

```
 Visibility="{Binding MyPropertytest}"
```

Comment: Implemented above code, this shows the label when results are back. Should actually show when button pressed and hide when results are back.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke not available in Viewmodel, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke is available but this is not taking given arguments

Comment: use this code, Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
               MyPropertytest = Visibility.Visible;
            }));

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your Button Command It worked fine for me

xaml

```
<Label Foreground="#6B666E" FontSize="10"  Content="Loading" x:Name="searchingLabel"  Visibility="{Binding LabelVisibility}" />
```

ViewModel

```
 private void ExecuteCommand(object obj)
    {
        LabelVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
       Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
      //// Do your code here

        LabelVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Comment: This shows the text when button pressed but does not hide when results are back. I added above code in SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { //above code here }. The do your code here part is inside command method, can not access lable there to set it's visibility to hidden again.

Comment: If you are using MVVM bind a visibilty for Label.Edited the answer.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render); is giving error in command method. Error 8 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Delegate, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, params object[])'

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to consider Model View View Model pattern to manage your App's navigation logic and contents. [(Channel9 introductive video)](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/kreekman/techdays-2010-understanding-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern)

As MVVM framework you could use [MVVM Light library](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) that exposes some useful methods.

In this case I would implement a `RelayCommand` to manage button's actions and `IValueConverter` to manage visibility of the contents.

**Your button's click behavior:**

```
private RelayCommand _searchCommand;
public RelayCommand SearchCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _searchCommand
            ?? (_searchCommand = new RelayCommand(
            async () =>
            {
                IsProcessing = true;
                // Your Logic, for example
                // await DoSomething
                IsProcessing = false;
            }
    }
}
```

**Your XAML for the button**:

```
<Button ... Command={Binding SearchCommand} ... />
```

**Your Visibility Converter:**

```
public class TrueCollapsedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Collapsed: Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Your property** to let your View know when you are processing something (Defined into your ViewModel's class):

```
public bool IsProcessing
{
    get
    {
        return _isProcessing;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_isProcessing == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _isProcessing = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsProcessing);
    }
}
```

Your XAML to **define the converter** (You can put it into App.xaml or Page.Resources tag):

```
<converters:TrueCollapsedConverter x:Key="TrueCollapsedConverter" />
```

Your XAML for the **object/objects that you want to manage visibility**:

```
<Label ... Visibility={Binding IsProcessing, Converter={StaticResource TrueCollapsedConverter} ... />
```